# Scan for open 80/443 port in unknown subnet

Tags: networking

I have a Zyxel Managed Switch somewhere in my network, but I don't know IP address of its interface. I don't want to reset the switch (for now)

It manages two separate vlans (and it's working), but it has web interface  on separate managemenet lan (VLAN=1, I suppose)

When I create interface `eno1.1` on my debian machine I can see broadcast messages from mac address, that matches Zyxel vendor

My idea is to assign an IP address to this interface and scan open 80/443 with nmap or other tool.

But is there way to automate it? I need to check 256 subnets

Or (somehow) I can scan that interface the other way?

Comment: If you need to access / find all ports on all subnets from one machine at one time, you need something like Solar Winds (generally a paid tool). If you can access one VLAN and then the other VLAN, you can use Advanced Port Scanner (Famatech) - free and one subnet at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I found `arp-scan`

I created an interface with VLAN 1, without IP address:

```
iface eno1.1 inet manual
```

and automated with simple one-liner:

```
for i in {0..255}; do echo 192.168.$i.0/24; sudo arp-scan -x -I eno1.1 --arpspa 192.168.$i.111 192.168.$i.0/24; done;
```

About `192.168.$i.111`: I remembered, that hosts has ips in the beginning of subnet (it turned out they were `x.x.x.3` and `x.x.x.4`), so I used `x.x.x.111` as IP address that won't conflict